# PHP echo returning the word 'Array'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

Been lurking on Stackoverflow for a long time but this is my first post. I am receiving a error related to displaying an array which is supposed to be populated by a mysql query. The echo function just returns `ArrayArrayArray` instead of what is supposed to be there. The mysql query is comparing a form input (the variable `$data`) .

```
<?php
$data = $_POST["search"];
global $data;

// Create Connection
$con = mysqli_connect(xxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx);

// Check Connection
if (mysqli_errno($con))

{
    echo "Failed To Connect To The Database" ;
}


//Perform Query To Compare And Return Results
$result_array = array();
$query = " SELECT url FROM data WHERE url LIKE '%$data%' "  ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
// While Loop To Return All Comparable Results
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 $result_array[] = $row['url'];

 echo $result_array ;


}
?>
```

Comment: use should use `print_r($result_array)` or `var_dump($result_array)`

Comment: not sure what your question is but to print an array use print_r($result_array)

Comment: It is not an error. It's just the way arrays are printed using the `echo` command. You should use something else (as suggested in the other comments) to print the contents of an array.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`echo`](https://www.php.net/echo) will print a string, try using something like [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/print_r) or [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) instead

**Example**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

`<pre>` will allow for easier reading of the array

Comment: Thanks for the help, print_r() and var_dump() do work, but I require a array because another piece of code has to use the results of the array.

Comment: Then just use the `$result_array` in that piece of code.

Comment: By any chance are you returning this array to another file, over something like AJAX? If so, why not use `echo json_encode($result_array);`

Answer (score 3):

You can try with following code.

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($result_array); echo '</pre>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` posts the string version of your variable, which in this case will look like Array.

You can use `var_dump($result_array);` or `print_r($result_array);` to get the results printed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you want to replace `echo $result_array;` by `echo  $row['url'];` (to display the content of url at each loop), or remove that line and add a `print_r($result_array);` after the `while{}` loop, to display all in one command.

Answer (score 1):

It's also useful use 
    echo implode(';', $result_array); 
for joining strings of each element in $result_array