# Converting MySQL column into custom array string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database with all the logins for my system. I'd like to basically query all the email addresses from those logins and put them into a variable so I can use that variable to send emails to everyone who has access.

Here's what I've got so far..

```html
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;dbhost=localhost', 'root', 'password');
$stmt2 = $db2->query("SELECT user_email FROM users ORDER BY user_id");
$useremails = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $useremails;
```

Unfortunately this just gives me a results of "Array"

I've tried this but it didn't work the way I need it to.. - [MySQL column into PHP array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681522/php-echo-returning-the-word-array)

The result I'd like the variable to read out is `"email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com"`

So that I can use it in my email sender like this..

```html
$to = "test1@testing.com, test2@testing.com, test3@testing.com, test4@testing.com";
```

so instead of writing them all out I would just put..

```html
$to = "$useremails";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply go like this:

```
$emailsStr = implode('; ', array_column($useremails, 'user_email'));
```