# Javascript function's argument is the word "Array" instead of a mySQL row

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

It appears that I am facing a common beginer's problem but I haven't managed to solved it on my code.

What I want to do:
I have created a database and I am currently working on a simple UI for updating it. So, I use

1. One drop-down menu populated by a mySQL table
2. Some forms with their values changed accordingly to the drop down selection.

Code(Simplified a little):

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown_id" onChange='fillFun(this.value)' >
            <option disabled selected value style="display:none"> -- select an option  -- </option>
            <?php
                //stuff pdo connection 
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDatabase", $user, $password);
                try
                {
                    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dbTable");
                    foreach($result  as $row)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row.'"';
                        echo '>'. $row['last_name'].' '. $row['first_name'].'</option>'."\n";
                    }
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'No Results'; }
            ?>
        </select >
    </form>

    <form id="forms" action="results.php" method="post">
        Last Name:      <input type="text" id="last_name" /><br><br>
        First Name:     <input type="text" id="first_name" /><br><br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function fillFun(fill)
        {   
            document.getElementById('last_name').value = fill[1];
            document.getElementById('first_name').value = fill[2];
        }
    </script>
<body>
```

Problem:

```
this.value = "Array"
```

After researching a little I found a couple of question with a similar problem.(For instace [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681522/php-echo-returning-the-word-array/21681550))
The thing is that I can't(or don't know how,to be precise) apply the given solution `print_r()` or `var_dump()` since I am echo-ing an option value. Another way to solve a similar problem was the use of `json_encode()` but after the change of

```
onChange='fillFun(this.value)'
```

with

```
onChange='fillFun(json_encode(this.value))'
```

the problem wasn't solved. On the contrary, it seems that now the `fill` parameter was null.(Nothing happens on change).

What am I missing here?Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it with `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`?

Comment: You're setting the `<option>` tag's value to the entire `$row` variable, rather than a specific column

Comment: @Geshode I tried it but the problem remains.
@iainn If I do `option value = row[first_name]` then I can correctly set first_name but I have no way to passing the last_name value. That's why I tried pass the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to `this.value` you can pass the `event` object to `fillFunc` function and obtain the value through `event.target.value`.

So `fillFunc` will be updated to:

```
fillFunc(event) {
   document.getElementById('last_name').value = event.target.value[1];
   document.getElementById('first_name').value = event.target.value[2];
}
```

And pass event to your `onchange` handler.,

`<select onchange="filFunc(event)"></select>`

Comment: @cgss, it's because of a problem with your PHP code, you pass an array to the option value. In HTML, option value default to be string. You don't want to pass the entire row to the value.You should pass only first_name and last_name to the option value, then you can you javascript split function to split the value and access them separately.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I need something like 
`stringForOptionValue = "row[first_name]-row[last_name]" 
option value = stringForOptionValue`
And inside the script `split(fill,-)`.
Is that what you mean? If yew then I guess I can try it but if you kindly provide a solution it would be much appreciated.